# Retornar colunas da tabela pivo belongsToMany Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom dia pessoa.

Criei uma busca que retorno as solicitações e quando clico abre os produtos dessa solicitação. Porem nao consigo fazer o produtos aparecerem como string, somente em formato de array como na imagem. Alguem sabe o que tenho feito de errado?

MODEL SOLICITAÇÃO

```
public function produto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class,'solicitacaodet');
}
```

MODEL PRODUTO

```
public function solicitacao()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Solicitacao::class,'solicitacaodet');
}
```

CONTROLLHER

```
public function create(){
  //    if(Gate::denies('equipamento-create')){       
  //    return view('admin._msg');
  // }
  $solicitacoes = Solicitacao::All();      

  $pessoas=DB::table('pessoasolcompvend')
    ->where('solicitante', '=', 's')
    ->orderby('pessoa')
    ->get();

  $unidades=DB::table('unidadeadm')       
  ->orderby('unidadeadm')
  ->get();

  $localentrega=DB::table('localentrega')           
  ->orderby('localentrega','asc')
  ->get();



    $caminhos = [
      ['url'=>'/home','titulo'=>'Inicio'],
      ['url'=>route('pedidocompra.index'),'titulo'=>'Pedido de Compra'],
      ['url'=>'','titulo'=>'Create'],
  ];
   return view('compra.pedidocompra.create',compact('solicitacoes','detalhes','pessoas','unidades','localentrega','produtos','centrocustos','caminhos'));
 }
```

VIEW

Solicitacao
                Data

```
      <?php foreach ($solicitacoes as $solicitacao){?>
        <tr style="background-color: #e1e1e1;color: black">                
            <td id="id"><a href="#"><?php echo $solicitacao->idsolicitacao?></a></td>   
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($solicitacao->data))?></td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">

                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                       <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Produto</th>
                          <th>Qnt</th>                
                          <th>Detalhe</th>                
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php 

                      $detalhes = $solicitacao->solicitacaodet;
                      $produtos = $solicitacao->produto;                          
                      $centrocusto = $solicitacao->centrocusto;


                      ?>                   

                      <?php foreach ($detalhes as $detalhe){?>                          
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $detalhe->produto_idproduto ?></td>
                        <td>
                          <?php 

                              echo $detalhe->produto()->select('produto')->get();
                              // echo $produto->produto

                          ?>                                
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $detalhe->qnt ?></td>                           
                        <td><?php echo $detalhe->detalhe ?></td>                           
                      </tr>
                       <?php } ?> 
                    </tbody>                        
                    </table>                        
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php } ?>           
    </tbody>
    </table>      



</div>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi, se você já pega os produtos pegando $produtos = $solicitacao->produto;
porque você faz o foreach em detalhes?
e ainda passa um get no final??
echo $detalhe->produto()->select('produto')->get();
fazendo um foreach em $produtos, ja traria um produto de cada vez, e lembro que o ->get() sempre vai retornar uma coleção para você

Comment: solicitacaodet e a tabela pivo. Nela vai idproduto/idcentrocusto(chaves estrangeiras) + qnt + detalhes do produto,  porem nao estou conseguindo mostrar a descrição do produto e do centro de custo apenas os ids. Ex eu faço um foreach de detalhes e nao trago descrição poduto, ou faço foreach produto e nao consigo consigo trazer os dados solicitacaodet.

Comment: Esta retornando  assim - > [{"PRODUTO":"CONJUNTO DE CABOS PARA CHUPETA"}].

Comment: mas dai você tem que passa a tabela pivot e os campos pivots na relação, algo assim:

public function solicitacao()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Solicitacao::class,'solicitacaodet')->withPivot('qnt','detalhes');
}

e dai você faz o foreach com produtos, e quando quiser imprimir os campos pivots você faz assim:
$produto->pivot->qnt

Comment: estou tentando mas esta dando erro. Uso pivot apenas na Solicitação ou na solicitacaodet tambem? Não estou sabendo como montar..

Comment: Vou postar como resposta, para ver se fica mais claro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Laravel, para acessar um valor presente numa tabela Pivot é necessário usar o atributo `pivot`.

Por exemplo, se você tem um relacionamento `N:N` de `Usuario` para `Produto`, você teria três tabelas: `usuarios`, `produtos` e `usuarios_produtos`, onde `usuarios_produtos` tem as colunas `produto_id`, `usuario_id` e `preco`

Você precisaria configurar o relacionamento na tabela `Usuario` assim:

```
// bastante atenção no plural em caso de relacionamentos que têm mais de um retorno
public function produtos()
{
      return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class, 'usuarios_produtos')->withPivot(['preco']);
}
```

Note que é necessário chamar `withPivot` para incluir "colunas extras" das tabela de relacionamento `N:N`.

Agora, bastaria chamar na view assim:

```
   @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
    O usuário {{ $usuario->nome }} tem os seguintes produtos:

    @foreach($usuario->produtos as $produto)
        O produto é {{ $produto->nome }} e o preço é {{ $produto->pivot->preco }}
    @endforeach

   @endforeach
```

Note que para acessar `preco`, que não está na tabela produto, e sim em `usuarios_produtos`, foi necessário chamar a propriedade `pivot`, pois nela contém os elementos de ligação entre as duas tabelas.

Comment: E no meu caso tenho relacionamento com 3 tabelas Solicitação -> (pivo=solicitacaodet) <-dentro dela vai Produto e Centro de Custos. Como seria

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou porem faltou a terceira tabela pra implementar que no caso seria centro de custos

Answer (score 0):

MODEL SOLICITAÇÃO (conferir se os campos ali no whitPivot estão certos com a sua tabela de ligação)

```
public function produto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class,'solicitacaodet')->whitPivot('qnt','detalhe');
}
```

CONTROLLHER

```
$solicitacoes = Solicitacao::All();
```

VIEW

```
$produtos = $solicitacao->produto;  

foreach($produtos as $produto){
  echo $produto->pivot->detalhe;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou porem faltou a terceira tabela pra implementar que no caso seria centro de custos –

Comment: Não entendi, a terceira tabela, mas é só criar ela na model também, e acessar através da função, igual as outras, só estiver na tabela pivot, é só adicionar os campos, se deu certo, por favor, de um voto positivo e como solucionado

Comment: Desculpa sou novo aqui,pra votar e so dar seta para cima mesmo? E pra finalizar como faço?

Comment: Sim para votar é setinha para cima, inclusive nos comentários, e para finalizar, você escolhe a resposta, e a marca como aceita!